# How can check Cassandra spread data evenly around the cluster

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am newbie in Cassandra, I create a Cluseter with following specification.

**How to make sure that Cassandra spread data evenly around the cluster?**

```
node count: 4
replication_factor: 3
```

table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE space.user (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname text,
    lastname text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `nodetool status` - you [can check](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsStatus.html) how much is shown in the `Load` column - that's amount of data on disk, although, it could count also the data that isn't cleaned (if you did the topology change, you may need to run `nodetool cleanup` to remove that data).

Basically, you shouldn't have very big differences between nodes, but this depends on the number that you specified as `num_tokens`. If you have 8 tokens per server, then difference could be +-10-12% from the average size. For higher number of tokens, the difference could be smaller.

But in your case I think that difference between nodes won't be very big because you have very small rows, and first name/last name should be very big.